# Please welcome your newest pro tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. I'm here today to announce that you're getting a great new pro tem moderator:

[image: Andrew Lott]

Andrew is taking the place of Sam Whited, who decided to step down for personal reasons. So without further ado, please join me in welcoming Andrew, as well as thanking Sam for his service!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm both honoured and excited to step into this role! I hope I can make a positive impact on the community and help make Tor more accessible to the masses.

Comment: Welcome Andrew! I'm looking forward to work with you. :-)

Comment: Welcome to the team!